# Excel Table created with VBA needing to populate with cells already populated with the vlookup formula

Tags: excel, vba

I have code pasted below that allows the user to create different size tables depending on the number they enter in the input box prompt.  This code works fine, but I have not been able to figure out how to get the table to be created with vlookup formulas already in it.  I would want all the cells in each row to reference the 1st columns cell for each row.

```
   Sub GenerateSupplyChain()
   Dim MySheet As String, ws As Worksheet
    MySheet = Sheets("Instructions").Range("T1").Value
    Set ws = Sheets(MySheet)
    
    Const COL_KEY = "O" ' used to determine the last row
    Const FIRST_ROW = 5
    Const HEADER_RNG = "D2:AS2" ' source of header
    Const BASE_SHT = "Base Data"
    Dim i As Variant
    i = InputBox("How many DFSP's in this Supply Chain?", "Enter Quantity")
    If Not IsNumeric(i) Then
        MsgBox "Please input a number.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If i < 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim oSht As Worksheet, LastRow As Long
    Set oSht = Sheets(MySheet)
    LastRow = oSht.Cells(oSht.Rows.Count, COL_KEY).End(xlUp).Row
    With oSht.Cells(LastRow, COL_KEY)
        If Len(.Value) > 0 Or (Not .ListObject Is Nothing) Then
            LastRow = LastRow + 2
        End If
        If LastRow < FIRST_ROW Then LastRow = FIRST_ROW
    End With
    Dim tabRng As Range, headerRng As Range, objTable As ListObject
    Set headerRng = Sheets("BASE Data").Range(HEADER_RNG)
    Set tabRng = oSht.Cells(LastRow, COL_KEY).Resize(i + 1, headerRng.Columns.Count)
    Set objTable = Worksheets(MySheet).ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, tabRng, , xlYes)
    objTable.HeaderRowRange.Value = headerRng.Value
    objTable.ShowTotals = True
    objTable.TableStyle = "TableStyleLight1"

    
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the line

```
objTable.TableStyle = "TableStyleLight1"
```

Add this:

```
objTable.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 6).Formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP([@[" & objTable.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 1).Value & "]],'BASE Data'!A:N,3,FALSE)"
```

Of course, the range to search and the column to return etc. needs to be changed from my example....